# Why does a comma transform the type into Line2D of an Axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm studying matplotlib and I have a question.

Why just putting a comma in `var_1`, the type of the variable changes completely, it becomes `Line2D`, while without the comma the type is `list` ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
var_1, = ax.plot([], [])
var_2 = ax.plot([], [])
print(type(var_1), type(var_2))

#<class 'matplotlib.lines.Line2D'> <class 'list'>
```

Comment: Note that the [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) command is very versatile, and you can plot multiple curves with just one function call.  For consistency, always a list of these curves (`Line2D`) is returned, also when there is only one curve created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ax.plot([], [])
```

is returning a list of length 1. In the first assignment, the comma indicates you're assigning contents of the list to the variable, similar to

```
 a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
```

or

```
 a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]
```

In your case, its the same as

```
a, = 1,
```

(Since `1,` generates a tuple (list-like object) of length one. )